# Javascript/php: xmlHttpRequest or (excluding header change ideally)

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php script which processes xml returned from an api call.  What I hope to achieve is to be able set the javascript as a bookmark, or better yet to load every time a document.location value changes. (currently set as bookmark).

The problem I'm having is gettin' passed the xmlHttpRequest's same server policy. As the php script requires that it is hosted on an external domain I can't access the php script to generate the results.

I've seen several scripts on the internet that apparently do it but they either carry out no function or still require accessing an external php script as a proxy.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript has certain rules for security reasons. This is one of them. In the alternative, you can pass the output of the script output from the php file to your server first before passing to your client. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the security reasoning for this but it's proving difficult.

Could you elaborate on your suggestion? I tried testing what I believe was your suggestion by trying to access sample.htm/sample.xml directly but they still return 200 ok (empty string)